# Am I getting crazy?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

I have been searching for 10 minutes why the first line gets a warning whereas the 3 last ones do not:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(displayWebServices) withObject:NULL atferDelay:0.5];

[self performSelector:@selector(displayWebServices) withObject:NULL afterDelay:0.5];

[self performSelector:@selector(displayWebServices) withObject:NULL afterDelay:0.5];

[self performSelector:@selector(displayWebServices) withObject:NULL afterDelay:0.5];
```

The warning is that RootViewController (self instance) may not respond to performSelectot:withObject:afterDelay.

I wonder whether there is a hidden character in the line...

Did you already face this same issue with XCode ?

Regards,
Apple92

Comment: Did it occur to you the warning is telling you exactly what is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change atferDelay to afterDelay.

Comment: Another proof that I do not read words entirely... well this is just the fact I have been coding for 18 hours... Should go to sleep now. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: It happens and you're not crazy.

Comment: @user255607: Good thing you pasted the code into the question instead of just writing it out anew.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina for having spent 18 hours programming you *must* be crazy.
...all programmers are, we know.